# jQuery Replace part of string using a variable

Tags: jquery, replace

This one seems simple, but I have no idea why it's not working.
I would like to replace part of a string in a variable.

Say, I have this code:

```
var url = "At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.";
url.replace('At vero eos et accusam et ', '');
```

Why doesn't it work?
This one works:

```
var url = "At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.".replace('At vero eos et accusam et ', ''):
```

-- but I'm using the variable elsewhere, so I would like to keep the replace  out of the variable definition.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PPgzv/).

Comment: because .replace() is not changing the string itself it is returning a new string:
http://jsfiddle.net/PPgzv/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to save the replaced string

```
  var url = "At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.";
  url = url.replace('At vero eos et accusam et ', '');
//^^^^^this
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PPgzv/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sethuramanP/PPgzv/2/)

```
     var url = "At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.";
     url=url.replace('At vero eos et accusam et ', '');
     $('#box').text(url);
```